# MariaDB 10.2 custom install using mysql_install_db.exe

Tags: mariadb, installation

In the past I used to setup MySQL/MariaDB manually on Windows boxes but don't remember exactly how. I unzip the .msi file and put every binary file into the desired place. I write a custom `my.ini` file including required `InnoDB` settings like `autoextend` but also log directory. Now I want to generate the `mysql` defaults database. According to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_install_dbexe/) it's not possible to provide the `mysql_install_db.exe` tool with a path to the `my.ini` file.
All files are generated into a single folder including a my.ini file I don't need.

How do I generate the database manually into my individual folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

I call `mysql_install_db.exe` with the correct `--datadir` argument and root password and have all files generated. I call `mysqld --remove` to delete the windows service. I call `mysqld --install-manual [ServiceName] --defaults-extra-file=my.ini` to finally set up the service using my very own `my.ini` file.
When this service is started up for the first time using `net start` the innodb-files are created freshly in the folders defined in the my.ini file. The system database `mysql` uses myisam table format and had not touched the innodb files.

Comment: mysql_install_db.exe does not create service if you do not ask for one, so you can skip mysqld --remove step